# how to stop Javascript forEach?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I'm playing with Node.js and Mongoose — trying to find specific comment in deep comments nesting with recursive function and `forEach` within. Is there a way to stop Node.js `forEach`? As I understand every `forEach` iteration is a function and and I can't just do `break`, only `return` but this won't stop `forEach`.

```js
function recurs(comment) {
    comment.comments.forEach(function(elem) {

        recurs(elem);

        //if(...) break;

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1259, accepted):

You can't break from a `forEach`. I can think of three ways to fake it, though.

**1. The Ugly Way**: pass a second argument to `forEach` to [use as context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=example), and store a boolean in there, then use an `if`. This looks awful.

**2. The Controversial Way**: surround the whole thing in a `try-catch` block and throw an exception when you want to break. This looks pretty bad and [may affect performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727905/in-javascript-is-it-expensive-to-use-try-catch-blocks-even-if-an-exception-is-n), but can be encapsulated.

**3. The Fun Way**: use  **[`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)**.

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].every(function(element, index) {
  // Do your thing, then:
  if (you_want_to_break) return false
  else return true
})
```

You can use **[`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** instead, if you'd rather `return true` to break.

Comment: +1, though it sounds more natural to me to use `some()` and `return true` when you want to break.

Comment: Or more elegantly, put `return !you_want_to_break` inside the loop instead of the if..else block.  Saves two lines.  :-)

Comment: `every` supported everywhere except IE7 & 8 (I had to look it up, so thought I'd share)

Comment: There should be number 4. The Beautiful Way: use `some()`

Comment: It should be the called 'misleading way'. The name suggests its the results not side effects you care about.

Comment: @jbobbins Yet another reason to drop IE8 support ;)

Comment: There's also a polyfill suggested by MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Polyfill.

Comment: Note also that since `some`/`every` returns `true` if any element does, you can go really crazy and nest this abuse arbitrarily deep..

Comment: Unfortunately using every() or some() will not solve cases where you would like to break on a specific value and return it. ECMAScript2015 new for...of (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) could help with that part but the drawback is that this solution can cause even more issues with older browsers.

If you are willing to change route completely and use a different more generic approach, a solution like this (https://github.com/nbouvrette/forEach) could help you and potentially solve even other headaches.

Comment: Regarding #2, you say it "may have bad performance" - why?

Comment: Can somebody explain the #1? How can it be done? Just interesting.

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE! `every` will only break with `== false` values whereas `some` will only break with `== true` values. Make sure you understand this concept before using this trick!

Comment: The 3rd way only end the every() loop. The following statements are still executed.

Comment: @slezica, could you please expand on "the ugly way"?

Comment: The second argument to `.forEach(callback, context)` is the `context` object, which can be accessed as `this` from within the callback. You could put an object there, with a property that tells you whether items should be processed or not. This still implies a linear walk down the array, unless you `throw`.

Comment: 3rd party libraries allows to use the same logic of `every`: if you return false, it will break the `each` Loop. In ES5 though, `every`is the way to go

Comment: How about maps?

Comment: Or you can make run 'forEach' in replica of your array, and when you want to break just 'splice' the main array, but we can't use this way everywhere. why don't we use 'for' or 'while' if we want to break the loop.

Comment: I ran into the same dilemma. I just converted forEach to good old "for" loop and used break and be done with it. The best part is, I need not to worry whether it works in all popular browsers.

Answer (score 75):

Breaking out of [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is not possible. (You can inspect the source code that implements it in Firefox on the linked page, to confirm this.)

Instead you should use a normal `for` loop:

```
function recurs(comment) {
    for (var i = 0; i < comment.comments.length; ++i) {
        var subComment = comment.comments[i];
        recurs(subComment);
        if (...) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

(or, if you want to be a little more clever about it and `comment.comments[i]` is always an object:)

```
function recurs(comment) {
    for (var i = 0, subComment; subComment = comment.comments[i]; ++i) {
        recurs(subComment);
        if (...) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible by throwing inside forEach function, as the accepted answer states.

Comment: sure is, but using exceptions to control program flow is a bad bad practice

Answer (score 59):

forEach does not break on return, there are ugly solutions to get this work but I suggest not to use it, instead try to use `Array.prototype.some` or `Array.prototype.every`

```js
var ar = [1,2,3,4,5];

ar.some(function(item,index){
  if(item == 3){
     return true;
  }
  console.log("item is :"+item+" index is : "+index);
});
```

Comment: it works but it will iterate all the member of the array

Comment: sorry there was a mistake, you need to do return true

Answer (score 42):

In some cases [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) will probably fulfil the requirements.

Comment: This should be the canonical answer as it will actually stop processing once it finds the correct element.  While `forEach` and `every` (as I understand it) can be hacked to return true on the first element it finds, it will still run through the entire array.  Secondly, Javascript doesn't perform tail optimization and thus all recursive functions are inherently fragile until ES6 comes out.

Comment: how is the browser support ?

Comment: @imalhasarangaperera Here you can find current browser support. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=example

Comment: @Indolering as per the docs, every() actually breaks once it returns false. some() differs in that you must return true to break.

Answer (score 31):

As others have pointed out, you can't cancel a `forEach` loop, but here's my solution:

```
ary.forEach(function loop(){
    if(loop.stop){ return; }

    if(condition){ loop.stop = true; }
});
```

Of course this doesn't actually break the loop, it just prevents code execution on all the elements following the "break"

Comment: I like this one. I would just combine the last line to `loop.stop = condition` though. It shouldn't make any difference because when it's set to `true` it won't be run anymore.

Comment: Clever use of named function expressions

Comment: I don't think this solution is a good idea. imagine you are looping 10000 elements and your condition is stop at second element, then you are going to do unnecessary iteration of 9998 times for nothing. The best approaches are either using `some` or `every`.

Comment: @Ali zyklus said that.... it's another, valid, solution! Depends on your case.... Why do people spend time on critisizing instead of presenting fresh new different solutions...?!?!?

Comment: @PedroFerreira my argument is valid. I'm not offending anybody. We need to be criticized about our code to make it better. I would rather read other implementation and help them improve it than reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @PedroFerreira The argument is valid for sure. However, in certain use cases when I know the number of elements isn't going to be very high, I would feel safe using it. It's good to have this as an option. :)

Comment: despite the early `return` condition, the `loop` function will still run for all elements in `ary`.

Answer (score 25):

I guess you want to use Array.prototype.[find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
Find will break itself when it finds your specific value in the array.

```
var inventory = [
  {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
  {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
  {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
];

function findCherries(fruit) { 
  return fruit.name === 'cherries';
}

console.log(inventory.find(findCherries)); 
// { name: 'cherries', quantity: 5 }
```

Comment: Note that this foreach will stop until return will true, otherwise it will still iterating until the end

Answer (score 11):

You can use Lodash's [`forEach`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#forEach) function if you don't mind using 3rd party libraries.

Example:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

_.forEach(comments, function (comment) {
    do_something_with(comment);

    if (...) {
        return false;     // Exits the loop.
    }
})
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    var f = "how to stop Javascript forEach?".split(' ');
    f.forEach(function (a,b){
        console.info(b+1);
        if (a == 'stop') {
            console.warn("\tposition: \'stop\'["+(b+1)+"] \r\n\tall length: " + (f.length)); 
            f.length = 0; //<--!!!
        }
    });
```

Comment: Nice one! I'd use third argument on callback though and length on it.

Answer (score 4):

`Array.forEach` cannot be broken and using `try...catch` or hacky methods such as `Array.every` or `Array.some` will only make your code harder to understand. There are only two solutions of this problem:

1) use a old `for` loop: this will be the most compatible solution but can be very hard to read when used often in large blocks of code:

```
var testArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for (var key = 0; key < testArray.length; key++) {
    var value = testArray[key];
    console.log(key); // This is the key;
    console.log(value); // This is the value;
}
```

2) use the new ECMA6 (2015 specification) in cases where compatibility is not a problem. Note that even in 2016, only a few browsers and IDEs offer good support for this new specification. While this works for iterable objects (e.g. Arrays), if you want to use this on non-iterable objects, you will need to use the `Object.entries` method. This method is scarcely available as of June 18th 2016 and even Chrome requires a special flag to enable it: `chrome://flags/#enable-javascript-harmony`. For Arrays, you won't need all this but compatibility remains a problem:

```
var testArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
for (let [key, value] of testArray.entries()) {
    console.log(key); // This is the key;
    console.log(value); // This is the value;
}
```

3) A lot of people would agree that neither the first or second option are good candidates. Until option 2 becomes the new standard, most popular libraries such as AngularJS and jQuery offer their own loop methods which can be superior to anything available in JavaScript. Also for those who are not already using these big libraries and that are looking for lightweight options, solutions like [this](https://github.com/nbouvrette/forEach) can be used and will almost be on par with ECMA6 while keeping compatibility with older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

*Below code will break the foreach loop once the condition is met, below is the sample example*

```
    var array = [1,2,3,4,5];
    var newArray = array.slice(0,array.length);
    array.forEach(function(item,index){
        //your breaking condition goes here example checking for value 2
        if(item == 2){
            array.length = array.indexOf(item);
        }

    })
    array = newArray;
```

Comment: does it will not create a memory leakage problem?

Comment: definitely it will not create memory leakage, because we are setting the original array with same exact data as it is, and it will not be dangling pointer, if you have still concern about newArray variable which was used above, after reassigning array = newArray you can set newArray= null

Comment: This does NOT break forEach even if it has the appearance of it. In this example it will still check if indices 2,3, and 4 exist.  If somehow those indices get populated again before their existences are checked, then the callback will still be called with  the new values.

Answer (score -6):

You can break from a forEach loop if you overwrite the Array method:

```
(function(){
    window.broken = false;

        Array.prototype.forEach = function(cb, thisArg) {
            var newCb = new Function("with({_break: function(){window.broken = true;}}){("+cb.replace(/break/g, "_break()")+"(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]));}");
            this.some(function(item, index, array){
                 newCb(item, index, array);
                 return window.broken;
            }, thisArg);
            window.broken = false;
        }

}())
```

example:

```
[1,2,3].forEach("function(x){\
    if (x == 2) break;\
    console.log(x)\
}")
```

Unfortunately with this solution you can't use normal break inside your callbacks, you must wrap invalid code in strings and native functions don't work directly (but you can work around that)

Happy breaking!

Comment: Never extend prototype, you might break things without knowing ant it will break your mind! Such a bad solution

Comment: Two bad practices in one code.

Answer (score -12):

Wy not use plain return?

```
function recurs(comment){
comment.comments.forEach(function(elem){
    recurs(elem);
    if(...) return;
});
```

it will return from 'recurs' function. I use it like this. Althougth this will not break from  forEach but from whole function, in this simple example it might work

Comment: You can not return in a loop

Comment: @Hazaart Although you can't do this in `forEach`, you can return in loops and the function will exit with no further iteration of the loop. (e.g. `for (... in ...)`, `while`, etc.)

Answer (score -17):

jQuery provides an `each()` method, not `forEach()`.  You can break out of `each` by returning `false`.  `forEach()` is part of the ECMA-262 standard, and the only way to break out of that that I'm aware of is by throwing an exception.

```
function recurs(comment) {
  try {
    comment.comments.forEach(function(elem) {
      recurs(elem);
      if (...) throw "done";
    });
  } catch (e) { if (e != "done") throw e; }
}
```

Ugly, but does the job.

Comment: -1 for spouting "use jquery" when the OP specifically said "node.js"

Comment: @cwolves I thought I saw "jQuery" in there somewhere.  Guess not, but heh anyhow because jQuery and node.js can be used in conjunction with one another.

Comment: no, you can't use jQuery in node.  If nothing else, there is an explicit reference to `window` which will throw an error if loaded in node.  Then you have all of the wasted code: The entire Sizzle engine, the entire jQuery root function (literally -- there's a reference to `document` in it -- it ___expects___ a DOM), etc.  The ONLY thing you can use from jQuery in node are a few of the helper functions, and those have clones in other libraries like underscore that are much better suited to node.

Comment: @cwolves Guess I'm getting rusty.  [I was thinking of Rhino](http://ejohn.org/blog/bringing-the-browser-to-the-server/).