# How to add value to an object inside function?

Tags: javascript

I loop through an array and depending on the conditions I want to add different values to an object.

The first console.log() outputs the value. The second one doesn't output anything. Why? And what can I do about it? The desired outcome is that if any of the keywords is inside nicecontact.fulladress, the string should be splitted and added using that keyword. if none of the values are, I want fulladress=adress

```
var niceContact= {}
niceContact.fulladress = $.trim(contact[2])
    //cut out lgh if it's in there.
    var keywords = ["Lgh", "lgh"]
    niceContact.adress = keywords.some(function(keyword){
        if (niceContact.fulladress.indexOf(keyword) != -1){
            adressarray = niceContact.fulladress.split(keyword)
            niceContact.adress = adressarray[0]
            console.log(niceContact.adress)

            return adress;
        }else{
            console.log('false')
            niceContact.adress = niceContact.fulladress
        }
    })
    console.log(niceContact.adress)
```

Comment: Can you please give us some example input for `contact[2]` that is showing the unexpected result?

Comment: Did you understand what [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) does and how it works? You seem to be abusing it. The last `console.log` will yield a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Thats not what `Array.some` is for. Shouldnt be returning a value from it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

> some executes the callback function once for each element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns a true value. If such an element is found, some immediately returns true. Otherwise, some returns false. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values.

```
var niceContact= {}
var hadHit = false
niceContact.fulladress = $.trim(contact[2])
    //cut out lgh if it's in there.
    var keywords = ["Lgh", "lgh"]
    niceContact.adress = niceContact.fulladress
    keywords.forEach(function(keyword){
        if (!hadHit && niceContact.adress.indexOf(keyword) != -1){
             // do your checking for the keywords here
             // and modify niceContact.adress if needed

             // if you're looking to `break` out of the .forEach
             // you can `return false;` instead (same as break) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260756/how-to-stop-javascript-foreach

             // or if you have a hit, just do `hadHit = true` after mod-ing the address

        }
    })
    console.log(niceContact.adress)
```

Comment: you dont need to, you just modify the value of `niceContact.adress` inside of it and if you want to return/short circuit, just `return false`

Comment: The problem is, that with my code. if the first one "Lgh" renders true, I don't want to iterate through the second one "lgh", because then it will overwrite the value I added to niceContact in the first one.

Comment: thats why you return false if you have a hit on lgh.

Comment: i just added a var to help you track if you had a hit-- `hadHit`