# Can forEach in JavaScript make a return?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I wonder if *forEach* in JavaScript can make a return, here is my code:

```
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

function fn(array) {
  array.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item === 2) return false;
  });

  return true;
}

var ans = fn(a);
console.log(ans); // true
```

I want to find out if 2 is in my array, if so, return false, but it seems that the *forEach* function has looped the whole array and ignore return.

I wonder if I can get the answer I want with *forEach* ( I know I can get what I want using for(..))? dear friend, pls help me, with great thanks!

Comment: There is a rather ugly workaround at http://stackoverflow.com/a/22187463/14955

Comment: Oh, wait - you want to know if you can return a value from the overall iteration? In that case, see my answer about using `.reduce()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use indexOf instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

```
function fn(array) {
  return (array.indexOf(2) === -1);
}
```

---

Also from the documentation for forEach - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

> Note: There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by
>   throwing an exception. If you need such behaviour, the .forEach()
>   method is the wrong tool, use a plain loop instead.

So, the return value cannot be used the way you are using it. However you could do a throw **(which is not recommended unless you actually need an error to be raised there)**

```
function fn(array) {
  try {
      array.forEach(function(item) {
         if (item === 2) throw "2 found";
      });
  }
  catch (e) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: my code is just a sample, my real purpose is to find weather a repeated item in a an array by using forEach...

Comment: @ZichiHan - I just edited my answer to cover that too. Short answer - you need to use a throw if you must do it that way. Cheers!

Comment: Why do you think *try..catch* is required?

Comment: @RobG - I think its not required and not recommended (see the bold portion in my answer). I was just illustrating how you can exit the forEach loop (since OP was wondering why it wasn't working and as mentioned in the MDN blockquote). Hope that's not too confusing. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

In this case `.indexOf()` is probably what you want, but there's also `.some()` when a simple equality comparison is *too* simple:

```
var ans = a.some(function(value) { return value === 2; });
```

The `.some()` function returns `true` if the callback returns `true` for any element. (The function returns as soon as the callback does return `true`, so it doesn't bother looking beyond the first match.)

You can usually use the `.reduce()` function as a more general iteration mechanism. If you wanted to count how many instances of `2` were in your array for example:

```
 var twos = a.reduce(function(c, v) { if (v === 2) c += 1; return c; }, 0);
```

Comment: my code is just a sample, my real purpose is to find weather a repeated item in a an array by using forEach...

Comment: @ZichiHan I don't understand what that means. Do you want to see if there is some particular item in an array more than once?

Comment: @ZichiHan oh wait, maybe I do understand - I think you should use `.reduce()` as I explain above.

Answer (score 1):

*forEach* returns *undefined* [by specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.foreach). If you want to find out if a particular value is in an array, there is *indexOf*. For more complex problems, there is *some*, which allows a function to test the values and returns *true* the first time the function returns *true*, or false otherwise:

```
a.some(function(value){return value == 2})
```

Obviously a trivial case, but consider if you want to determine if the array contains any even numbers:

```
a.some(function(value){return !(value % 2)})
```

or as an ECMA2015 arrow function:

```
a.some(value => !(value % 2));
```

If you want to test if a particular value is repeated in an array, you can use [*lastIndexOf*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype.lastindexof):

```
if (a.indexOf(value) != a.lastIndexOf(value) {
  // value is repeated
}
```

or to test for any duplicates, again *some* or *every* will do the job:

```
var hasDupes = a.some(function(value, i, a) {
  return a.lastIndexOf(value) != i;
});
```

An advantage of *some* and *every* is that they only process members of the array until the condition is met, then they exit whereas *forEach* will process all members regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Others have mentioned `.indexOf()` and `.some()`.  I thought I would add that a good old fashioned `for` loop gives you the absolute most iteration control because you control the iteration and your processing code is not embedded in a callback function.

While `.indexOf()` already does exactly what you need, this code just shows how you can directly return when using the old fashioned `for` loop.  It is somehow out of favor these days, but is often still the best choice for better looping control.

```
function fn(array) {
  for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (array[i] === 2) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Using the `for` loop, you can iterate backwards (useful when removing items from the array during the iteration), you can insert items and correct the iteration index, you can immediately return, you can skip indexes, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You said you want with forEach, so I modified your code:

```
function fn(array) {
    var b = true;
    array.forEach(function (item) {
        if (item === 2) {
            b = false;
        }
    });
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

function fn(array, callback) {
  var r = true;
  array.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item === 2) r = false;
  });

  callback(r);
}

fn(a, function(data) {
console.log(data) //prints false.
});
```

You can use `callbacks` as mentioned above to return the data you need. This is not same as the return statement but you will get the data.