# how could i return the value inside of a foreach javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, ecmascript-6

I have a function that needs to return the id of a country.

My list is an array of objects :

```
{
    id: 2,
    code: "AL",
    name: "Albania"
}...
```

Here is my function to get the id needed from   country

```
getCountryID(countryName) {
            return country_list_with_id.forEach(res => {
                if (res.name.toLowerCase() === countryName) {
    console.log("the id is",res.id)// the log is 143
                    let id = res.id;
                    return id;
                }
            });
        }
    console.log(array.getCountryID("USA"))//undefined
```

so how could I get the id?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can forEach in JavaScript make a return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041912/can-foreach-in-javascript-make-a-return)

Comment: `toLowerCase() === countryName`  `countryName = "USA"`  never going to happen..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `filter` your array of countries to get the country you want, and return result. `countries[0]` might be `undefined` so use an if statement from my example or ternary operator from [@void](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1496715/void)'s example Here's the snippet:

```js
const countries = [{ id: 2, code: "AL", name: "Albania" }, { id: 3, code: "DZ", name: "Algeria" }, { id: 4, code: "DS", name: "American Samoa" }];
function getCountryId(code) {
  const country = countries.filter(country => country.code === code);
  if(country.length > 0) {
    return country[0].name;
  } else {
    return "No such country.";
  }
}
console.log(getCountryId("DZ"));
console.log(getCountryId("USA"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't. `forEach` is not intended to return anything, but you can use another function to get the `id` from the array.

Using `find` will return you an object which is satisfies your condition.

```
getCountry(countryName) {
    return country_list_with_id.find(item => item.name.toLowerCase() === countryName);
}
```

This will return the `country` object and from that object you can inject the id. If nothing was found, `undefined` is returned. So you need to check that object first, then try to access its properties.

```
const country = array.getCountry("USA");

console.log(country && country.id);
```

Comment: This is the most logical solution if you don't care about prehistoric browsers :-) Nice job.

Comment: @user3492940 `if you don't care about prehistoric browsers`  On SO, we don't.  For these outdated & security issued browsers, we pollyfill & transpile.. :)

Comment: Recently I have read a blog where a person says that you don't need to care about prehistoric browsers, force them to upgrade the browser :). Nevertheless Javascript must go to the production with transpiled version and polyfills

Comment: @SurenSrapyan  Indeed, otherwise we would be spending 50% of our time answering questions by having code to show how it's done in older browsers.  IMO: All answers unless the OP says otherwise should assume ES6 is fine.

Comment: Not saying you should care about them, but something worth mentioning because not everyone has the luxury of ignoring the dinosaurs among us.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` in order to filter out the country by name, and then return the `id` of the `first/last` item.

```js
const list = [{
  id: 2,
  code: "AL",
  name: "Albania"
}, {
  id: 3,
  code: "DZ",
  name: "Algeria"
}, {
  id: 4,
  code: "DS",
  name: "American Samoa"
}];


function getCountryId(name) {
  return (list.filter((country) => country.name === name)[0] || {}).id;
}


console.log(getCountryId('Algeria'));
console.log(getCountryId('NoneExistingCountry'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use need to use `.filter` here. This will return the items from array matching specific condition

```js
 var data = [{ id: 2, code: "AL", name: "Albania" }, { id: 3, code: "DZ", name: "Algeria" }, { id: 4, code: "DS", name: "American Samoa" }]

Array.prototype.getCountryID = function(code){
  var output = this.filter(el => el.code === code);
  return output.length > 0 ? output[0].id : "Not Found";
}

console.log(data.getCountryID("DS"));
console.log(data.getCountryID("something else"));
```