# forEach is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, loops

I want my foreach() to loop through an array of maps and check if the type value matches. If not return the else statement.

**Function**

```
function checkCars(carData) {
        const cars = carData.models;

        models.forEach(model => {
            if (model.type === 'Toyota' || model.type === 'Hyundai') {
                return "Type A";
            } else {
                return "Type B";
            }
        });
    }
```

**Database**

```
"models": [
  {type: "Toyota"}
  {type: "Hyundai"}
  {type: "Audi"}
  {type: "VW"}
]
```

Comment: you are iterating over model instead of cars.

Comment: Use another variable to hold type and return that outside for each in function

Comment: It’s better to provide your expected output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can forEach in JavaScript make a return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32041912/can-foreach-in-javascript-make-a-return)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is `undefined`, you can not return anything explicitly from `forEach()`.

You can try with [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead:

> The [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
function checkCars(carData) {
  const cars = carData.models;

  return models.map(model => {
    if (model.type === 'Toyota' || model.type === 'Hyundai') {
      return "Type A";
    } else {
      return "Type B";
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What about breaking the loop when the first `if` is true?

Comment: @aszet, you can not even brake the loop, they are bound to execute for all the elements in the array. To break the loop you have to use simple *for* loop.

Comment: @aszet If you want some, use `.some()`, if you want all use `.every()`. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for examples.

Answer (score 2):

forEach has no return value. You should use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to change the element's types.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transform the array, you want [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
function checkCars(carData) {
  const cars = carData.models;

  return models.map(model => {
    if (model.type === 'Toyota' || model.type === 'Hyundai') {
      return "Type A";
    } else {
      return "Type B";
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific about what the issue is, then. What output *do* you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
function checkCars(carData) {
        const cars = carData.models;
        let type = "Type A"
        models.forEach(model => {
            if (model.type !== 'Toyota' && model.type !== 'Hyundai') {
                type = "Type B";
            }
        });
        return type
    }
```