# How to stop a forEach loop in Typescript - can I use .some()?

Tags: foreach, typescript, break, es5-shim

I've seen [this question about stopping a ES5 forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260756/how-to-stop-javascript-foreach), which pretty much suggests to use .every() or .some() instead of forEach.

I believe I remember typescript uses shims for old browsers to support for example forEach.
Is this correct and if so, can I use .some and .every just as well with the same kind of support as forEach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I believe I remember typescript uses shims for old browsers to support for example forEach. Is this correct

No. TypeScript has no runtime additions for shimming the compilied JavaScript (beyond the `__extends` function).

> can I use .some and .every just as well with the same kind of support as forEach?

Here is the compatability table : http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.prototype.some that you need to check for your browser.

Answer (score 1):

I've found part of the answer already with [this ES5 compatibility page](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.prototype.some), which shows everything from IE9 and up supports .forEach, .every and .some, so no shims are needed for that.