# forEach shows x times the rows message

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a check inside a `forEach()` because there are x rows inside the output it shows me x times the error.
Lets pretent var compare outputs 1,2,3,4

```
compare.forEach(function(item){
 if(input == item){
   console.log('Succes');
 } else {
  // So if input does not equals the arrays
  console.log('error');
 }
});
```

Now because i have 4 items in the output i get `4` times the `console.log('error');` how must I avoid the 4 times error show ?

Comment: use `break;` after the console.log to stop the loop from iterating further.

Comment: @treegarden `break;` doesn't work with the `forEach` function.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I learned something new ;) well I found a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6260865/3955740)

Comment: @treegarden, thanks it worked for me changed forEach() to every() the guy who marked it, linked to a bad solution :)