# Javascript Look through Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

First time posting a question. Hunted through stackoverflow for the answer but didn't find it. If I missed it, and this is a duplicate question, please comment a link and I'll delete this! (newbie here)

So basically, I have an array `them_dogs` containing objects. I am trying to write a function that accepts an array and an object value, say `'tennis ball'`. This function will then look through each item in the array and check to see if the value `'tennis ball'` is present. If so, it will return the item name.

```
var them_dogs = [{
        name: 'Henry',
        age: 0.5,
        breed: 'Aussie',
        food: 'kibble',
        toys: ['tennis ball', 'chew toy'],
        picture: 'http://rubyriverminiaustralianshepherds.com/wp-content/uploads/aussie-puppy-for-sale-940x412.jpg'
    }, {
        name: 'Tilly',
        age: 5,
        breed: 'Mutt',
        food: 'kibble',
        toys: ['bone', 'kong', 'squeaky toy'],
        picture: 'http://www.dogchannel.com/images/zones/top_promo/excited-mixed-breed.jpg'
    }, {
        name: 'Apollo',
        age: 10,
        breed: 'Labrador',
        food: 'absolutely anything',
        toys: ['old sock', 'other old sock', 'more old socks'],
        picture: 'http://media.cmgdigital.com/shared/img/photos/2014/08/01/5a/66/LadyLabrador.jpg'
    }]
```

Here is the function

```
    var findDogByToy = function (arr, toyname) {
      arr.forEach (function (item) {
        if (item.toys === toyname) {
          return item.name;
        }
      })
    }

findDogByToy(them_dogs, 'tennis ball');
```

Comment: Using forEach is not the right solution when you want to find one item. What happens if two animals have the same toy?

Comment: @epascarello, good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, using forEach to solve this problem is a naive approach, however for beginners to Array functions, this explanation may prove to be useful for your understanding:

```
function findDogByToy(array, toy) {
  // loop across each item in the array
  var result;
  array.forEach(function(dog) {
    // check that item (which is an object) to see if toy is in there
    dog.toys.forEach(function(item) {
      //if it is, then return item name
      if (item === toy) {
        result = dog.name;
      }
    });
  });
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of `forEach`, use `every`. `every` is cleaner since you are not looking to modify **any** elements. Also, it is harder to break out of a `forEach`. See [how to stop Javascript forEach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260756/how-to-stop-javascript-foreach)
2. Use `indexOf` to detect if the `toyname` exists in the `toys` array
3. `findDogByToy` needs to actually **return** a value to benefit the caller

```js
var them_dogs = [{
  name: 'Henry',
  age: 0.5,
  breed: 'Aussie',
  food: 'kibble',
  toys: ['tennis ball', 'chew toy'],
  picture: 'http://rubyriverminiaustralianshepherds.com/wp-content/uploads/aussie-puppy-for-sale-940x412.jpg'
}, {
  name: 'Tilly',
  age: 5,
  breed: 'Mutt',
  food: 'kibble',
  toys: ['bone', 'kong', 'squeaky toy'],
  picture: 'http://www.dogchannel.com/images/zones/top_promo/excited-mixed-breed.jpg'
}, {
  name: 'Apollo',
  age: 10,
  breed: 'Labrador',
  food: 'absolutely anything',
  toys: ['old sock', 'other old sock', 'more old socks'],
  picture: 'http://media.cmgdigital.com/shared/img/photos/2014/08/01/5a/66/LadyLabrador.jpg'
}];

var findDogByToy = function(arr, toyname) {
  var name;
  arr.every(function(item) {
    if (item.toys.indexOf(toyname) > -1) {
      name = item.name;
      return false;
    }
  });
  return name;
}


console.log(findDogByToy(them_dogs, 'tennis ball'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to use filter() and map() and not forEach(). This way if you have more than one, you will get an array of names.

```js
var them_dogs = [{
        name: 'Henry',
        age: 0.5,
        breed: 'Aussie',
        food: 'kibble',
        toys: ['tennis ball', 'chew toy'],
        picture: 'http://rubyriverminiaustralianshepherds.com/wp-content/uploads/aussie-puppy-for-sale-940x412.jpg'
    }, {
        name: 'Tilly',
        age: 5,
        breed: 'Mutt',
        food: 'kibble',
        toys: ['bone', 'kong', 'squeaky toy'],
        picture: 'http://www.dogchannel.com/images/zones/top_promo/excited-mixed-breed.jpg'
    }, {
        name: 'Apollo',
        age: 10,
        breed: 'Labrador',
        food: 'absolutely anything',
        toys: ['old sock', 'other old sock', 'more old socks'],
        picture: 'http://media.cmgdigital.com/shared/img/photos/2014/08/01/5a/66/LadyLabrador.jpg'
    }]

    var findDogByToy = function (arr, toyname) {
      return arr.filter (function (item) {
        return item.toys.indexOf(toyname) > -1;
      }).map( function(o){ return o.name; });
    }

console.log(findDogByToy(them_dogs, 'tennis ball'));
```

Other option, just use a simple for loop and push to an array.

Comment: Happens all the time! ;)

Comment: nice approach using `filter` and **yes** the OP could definitely make use of having multiple names returned instead of the first one