# How to send return statement to parent function?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, return

Not sure how to explain this. I'll try it with an example.

For example, I use the following function as a short for a `for` loop over an array:

```
function forEach(array, f) {
  var len = array.length, i;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
    f(i, array[i], len);
  }
};
```

I guess this is not too uncommon. But it leads to problems when replacing the following `for` loop within a function:

```
function test(someArray) {
  for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    if (someArray[i] === 23) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

The replacement:

```
function test(someArray) {
  forEach(someArray, function(i, value) {
    if (value === 23) {
      return true;
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

Does not return the function `test` when 23 is reached and returns `true` but keeps executing the statements after the `forEach` and returns `false`.

Comment: please add some data and the wanted result. checking for `23` can lead to `true`, `23`, or a collection of `[23, 23]`.

Comment: @NinaScholz Well, this is only an example. I am looking for an all purpose solution. I thought maybe there is a way to send a return statement directly further on to the parent function. But probably there is no such thing.

Comment: @gavgrif Thanks. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please use for a callback the same style as in the API for array. Then use the callback as check and leave the decision to the calling function to use the information.

In this case the callback looks for a number and return `true` if the element is equal to `23`. The calling function stops the iteration when receiving `true` and return `true`. Otherwise the iteration goes on and if not found, the return value is `false`.

```js
function forEach(array, f) {
    var len = array.length,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i ++) {
        if (f(array[i], i, array)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var cb = function (v) { console.log('value', v); return v === 23; };

console.log('result', forEach([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 23, 6, 7], cb));
console.log('result', forEach([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 33], cb));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For a different approach, like to get a value back, I suggest to return the item instead of a boolean value. If not found, return `undefined`.

```js
function forEach(array, f) {
    var len = array.length,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i ++) {
        if (f(array[i], i, array)) {
            return array[i];
        }
    }
}

var cb = function (v) { console.log('value', v); return v === 23; };

console.log('result', forEach([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 23, 6, 7], cb));
console.log('result', forEach([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 33], cb));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Does the loop get much slower due to the `if` check?

Comment: Would your solution take care of, say, two nested `forEach` where the inner function sends the return statement?

Comment: it depends what `forEach` return.  the original [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does only iterate with the callback. [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns an array with the items while the callback retuns a boolean value, as in the above cases. so yes, it could, depending on the staye and purpose of your own `forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `forEach()` function needs to return a value. Otherwise of course you will always return `false` after calling `forEach()`.

```
function forEach(array, f) {
  var len = array.length, i;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
    if (f(i, array[i], len)) {
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};

function test(someArray) {
  return forEach(someArray, function(i, value) {
    return value == 23;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of achieving the effect. This is a simple one:

```
function test(someArray) {
  var result = false

  forEach(someArray, function(i, value) {
    if (value == 23) result = true;
  });

  return result;
}
```

Note that `value` should be compared with `==`. A single `=` is for assignment, it just replaces `value`.

The disadvantage of using `forEach` here is that the loop *won't stop when `value` is `23`*. It will finish interating through all the items, even if `23` is the first on the list. With the `for-return` combo, iteration stops as soon as `23` is found.

If this worries you, there's  [a trick or two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260756/how-to-stop-javascript-foreach) for stopping `forEach`, but the `for-return` approach is cleaner.