# How to break foreach loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I have an object **mobile_specs** which have several fields such as DeviceName, Brand, Camera.
I loop though the **mobile_specs** object so that i can print the specifications of two mobiles in tabular format:

```
var i=0;
Object.keys(mobile_specs).forEach(function(key) {
                       if(i==5)
                       {
                        break;
                       }
                      var mobile1=mobile_specs.[key];
                      var mobile2=mobile_specs.[key];
                      alert(mobile1 + " " +mobile2);
                      i++;
                });
```

But the above code give me an error which is:

```
Illegal break statement
```

**How can i break my loop when i==5 ?**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: instead of a `break` use a `return` You can not technically break out of `forEach`, use a `for` otherwise.

Comment: [There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Note that having a counter in this case does not make much sense, as objects' properties are not ordered. Which means that you may have different first five outputs depending on the engine/browser you're using.

Comment: You should refer this question, here it is explained in detail - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260756/how-to-stop-javascript-foreach

Comment: Side note for your future understanding... There's no actual *loop* in your code.  That's a function call.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break

Comment: instead of starting the forEach, take the values of Object.keys in a variable. Then you can use normal for loop with that variable and there break will work

Comment: Thank you @David

Answer (score 9):

There is no way to stop or break a `forEach()` loop other than by throwing an exception. I think `forEach` is not suited for your job, use a simple loop instead

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break