# Promise and Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, foreach, promise

I need your help for a "simple" problem but the promise is again a mistake for me...

This is un exemple of my code.

```
 // In a middleware, i have a mongoose request

Request
.find({ user: req.user.email })
.then(function (allDatasets) {
    allDatasets.forEach(function (oneDataset) {
        if (oneDataset.use_case == reqParams.use_case) {
            res.status(400).json({
                'msg': 'My response'
            })
        }
    })
})

// And my code continue...
```

I would like that if if condition is true, node return this response and stop the code ! But.. Node is asynchronous and while my loop is running, the code below is executed.

I tried to put the code below in a .then () but it does not wait for the end of the loop to continue to execute the code ...

Thank you for your help

Comment: you maybe need to clarify your issue.... maybe you want to make the `function (oneDataset)` an `async function (oneDataset)` and then await some code?

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann you can't stop a forEach by returning. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260756/how-to-stop-javascript-foreach

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the problem you have is. The for each definitely can cause a problem if there's more than one thing in it that satisfies the requirements of the response. but because you mentioned promises, i wonder if maybe you'r problem is related to a loop that isn't present in your code sample... otherwise, promises would be irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: I want that Node wait the total execution of forEach 
before continuing...

Comment: @Zarathoustra75 Why? that makes no sense given the code in your question. Nothing in the forEach is worth waiting for.

Comment: Also... Why does the forEach in your question exist? couldn't you have just made that if statement part of your mongoose query the same way req.user.email is?

Comment: @kevinB 
If use_case exists, I go out and return that answer. My code is finished.

Otherwise, if it does not exist, I have a whole treatment to do on my file. So if, it is important to wait because otherwise forEach is useless since the rest of the code runs anyway.

Comment: You'll have to return to the promise a value that represents the fact that none were found, and chain off of it recursively until one is. But your question doesn't contain enough code for anyone to help you with that.

Comment: Thank you for your help @kevinB 
Finally a use this plan.

//Before the code
return request.findOne({user: user, use_case:  use_case}), function(err, obj){
if (err){
console.log(err)
}
if (obj != null){
My response
}
.then(function(){
The reste of code, only execute if obj is null
})

Answer (score 2):

I think what you actually want is

```
Request.find({ user: req.user.email })
.then(function (allDatasets) {
    if (allDatasets.some(oneDataset => oneDataset.use_case == reqParams.use_case)) {
        res.status(400).json({
           'msg': 'My response'
        })
    } else {
        // And my code continue...
    }
});
```

Comment: Well tried but I have a lot of code below with functions and this method breaks all the rest of the code.

I would like to use NodeJS methods to solve my problem.

Comment: Well if you have a lot of code that needs to wait for the `Request.find()`, then you have a lot of code that needs to go inside the `then` handler. (Or in a function that is called from there, of course). There's no way around that.

Comment: Maybe `async`/`await` syntax can simplify your code, but conceptually that's the same.

Answer (score 0):

Best way, you can use async function
    const allDatasets = await Request.find({ user: req.user.email });

```
allDatasets.forEach(function (oneDataset) {
    if (oneDataset.use_case == reqParams.use_case) {
        res.status(400).json({
            'msg': 'My response'
        })
    }
})
//you can continue your code here
```