# Turning for loop into forEach JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

Working on a function that verifies if each number in an `array` is `true` or `false` and returns the first true `number`.

Have a working solution with a for loop as follows:

```
function findElement(arr, func) {
  var num;
  for (var a = 0; a < arr.length; a++) {
    if (func(arr[a])) {
      num = arr[a];
      return num;
    }
  }
  return num;
}

findElement([1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10], function(num) {
  return num % 2 === 0;
})
// Should return 8
```

But I'm trying (in order to get my head around `forEach` better) to convert it into a `forEach` loop.

This is where I am so far, but I don't see how to actually return the `num` out of the loop after it's been established that the function result is true:

```
function findElement(arr, func) {
  if (arr.forEach(func) === true) {
    return num;
  }
}
findElement([1, 2, 3, 4], num => num % 2 === 0);
```

Comment: `var num; if (num = arr.find(func)) return num;`

Comment: `forEach` can't do an early return.

Comment: @Ele Ah I need to learn about .find - it looks perfect for this (alongside .filter(func)) but I was looking to learn about forEach!

Comment: So do you want an implementation of forEach ?

Comment: `forEach` is not always better than a "simple" `for`. That being said, `forEach` does not return anything, and it also ignores what the passed callback function returns.

Comment: @daggett `forEach` isn't a good choice for this particular problem. In fact, I rarely find it useful when working with arrays. [`map`, `filter`, and `reduce` can do most of the heavy lifting](https://zzzzbov.com/blag/functional-shape-of-loops), although there are a lot of other iterative patterns. Your function would probably be better written as `first([1, 2, 3, 4], num => num % 2 === 0)` which could take a predicate and return the first result that matches the predicate.

Comment: @zzzzBov Right I see - so for this case the real problem is down to the fact that `forEach` just really isn't the one to use, but I still wonder if forEach can be made to work, just from an understanding of the method point of view

Comment: @daggett absolutely, if you used a `for` loop without a `break`, you could get it to work by setting a variable external to the loop. The exact same thing can be done with `forEach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how to use `forEach` but you could use [array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter):

```
function findElement(arr, func) {
  return arr.filter(func)[0];
}
```

[@cdhowie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501250/cdhowie) suggested the use [array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find) in order to need the usage of `[0]`.

```
function findElement(arr, func) {
  return arr.find(func);
}
```

Obviously, that is just a guess because it may raise an error if no item in the array meets the requirements of `func`.

If you still are looking about use `forEach` maybe you could do something like this:

```
function findElement(arr, func) {
  matches = []
  arr.forEach((item) => {
      if (func(item)) {
          matches.push(item)
      }
  });
  return matches[0];
}
```

Or:

```
function findElement(arr, func) {
  match = null
  arr.forEach((item) => {
     match = (match == null && func(item)) ? item : match
  });
  return match;
}
```

Again, you will have to check how to handle the error if no item in the array meets the requirements f your `func`.

Any of both codes produce

```
console.log(findElement([1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10], function(num) { return num % 2 === 0; })))
8
```

Comment: Yep, this works - I have this solution too I was just wondering about the capabilities of forEach!

Comment: @daggett, I've added an example with forEach.

Comment: `arr.filter(func)[0]` is better expressed as `arr.find(func)`. The former will iterate the whole array, while the latter will stop on the first match.

Answer (score 1):

```
function findElement(arr, func) {

    var num;

    arr.forEach(function(element) {
        if (!num && func(element)) {
            num = element;
          }
    });

    return num;
  }
```

For more options you can check this question: [how to stop Javascript forEach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260756/how-to-stop-javascript-foreach)

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned, this is not how `forEach` should be used.

However, you can still get the behavior you want:

```
function findElement(arr, func) {
  var num;

  arr.forEach(item =>{
    if (func(item)) {
      num = item;
      // .forEach does not have an early return
      // but you can force it to skip elements by removing them
      while (true) {
        // Remove all elements
        var removedItem = arr.shift();
        if (removedItem === undefined) {
          // All elements removed
          break;
        }
    }
  }
  return num;
}
```

This is even mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#If_the_array_is_modified_during_iteration_other_elements_might_be_skipped.)

Answer (score -1):

maybe like this

```
function findElement(arr, func) {
  var num = null;

  for (var a = 0; a < arr.length && num === null; a++) {
    var val = arr[a];
    num = func(val) ? val : null; 
  }
  return num;
}

console.log(findElement([1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 10], function(num) {
  return num % 2 === 0;
}));
```

Comment: and where is forEach ?

Answer (score -1):

here is your findElement method with foreach

```
function findElement(arr, func) {
var num = 0;

arr.forEach(function(item){
 if (func(item))
    return item;
  })
return num;
}
```

Comment: This will always return 0, as forEach cannot do an early return