# Angular replace double iteration with lambda expression

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there some simple way to write this block of code:

```
  this.markersDisplay = this.markersSource;

    // Filter Marker Type
    if (this.isValid(this.selectedMarkersType)) {
      let markers: Array<Marker> = new Array<Marker>();
      for (let marker of this.markersDisplay) {
        for (let markerType of this.selectedMarkersType) {
          if (marker.MarkerType == markerType) {
            markers.push(marker);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      this.markersDisplay = markers;
    }
```

I would like to replace **double for iteration** with some lambda expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the `break` statement you can use this

```
markers = this.markersDisplay
    .filter((marker: Marker) => (this.selectedMarkersType
            .find((markerType: MarkerType) => markerType === marker.MarkerType)));
```

If you don't work with types:

```
markers = this.markersDisplay
    .filter(marker => (this.selectedMarkersType
            .find(markerType => markerType === marker.MarkerType)));
```

If you need to use the `break` statement for performance you can't use arrow functions. Instead, use [some() or every() functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260865/3681565):

```
markers = this.markersDisplay
    .filter(marker => (this.selectedMarkersType
            .some(markerType => markerType === marker.MarkerType)));
```

You can see this happening [in this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9vfjbm)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
markers = markersDisplay.filter(x=>{
    return selectedMarkersType.find((curVal,i)=>{
        return x.MarkerType==curVal;
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a couple of assumptions with regards to your data structure, but I hope the below code will work for you.

```
this.markersDisplay.forEach((p) => {
        p.MarkerType.filter(p => p.MarkerType === this.selectedMarkersType).map(p => markers.push(marker));
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `Array.forEach` method.

```
this.markersDisplay = this.markersSource;

// Filter Marker Type
if (this.isValid(this.selectedMarkersType)) {
  let markers: Array<Marker> = new Array<Marker>();
  this.markersDisplay.forEach(md => {
    this.selectedMarkersType.forEach(mt => {
      if (md.MarkerType === mt) {
        markers.push(md);
      }
    });
  });
  this.markersDisplay = markers;
}
```