# Javascript returning in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, foreach, try-catch

I run in to this scenario a lot and would just like to know if my solution is the best and if there might be something better. Many cases I have a `forEach` loop, and I want to check if any of the values are incorrect, if they are, end the code (`return`). Here is what I would do without a loop:

```
const email = '...';
if (email.isInvalid) return;
```

In a loop I would do this:

```
const emailList ['...', '...', '...'];
const emailErrors = [];

emailList.forEach((element) => {
    // if (element.isInvalid) return; // This won't work here, it just ends this loop instance, which is my problem
    if (element.isInvalid) emailErrors.push(element);
});

if (emailErrors.length > 0) return; // This will end the code correctly
```

Is there any better approach to this idea? Using `try, catch` or something else?

Comment: Read this-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260756/how-to-stop-javascript-foreach

Answer (score 0):

You can't `break` from `forEach`. It will run on every element of the array. You can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if at least one of the items is `isInvalid`. This will short-circuit once an item with `isInvalid = true` is found

```
if (emailList.some(element => element.isInvalid))
  return
```

Answer (score 0):

Your forEach execute [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for each element and not check its result. I not recommend using `try-catch` because it is very slow. Try to use `for-of` with `return` (or `break` to not return but only break for loop and continue execution code below `for`)

```js
function start() {
  const emailList = ['abc@test.com', 'invalid 1', 'invalid 2'];
  const emailErrors = [];

  for(let element of emailList)
  {
    console.log(element);
    if(!/@/.test(element)) return;  // some validation (missing @ char)
  };

}

start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array​.prototype​.every().

The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

```
function validateEmailList(element) {
  return element.isInvalid;
}

console.log(emailList.every(validateEmailList));
```