# Question about forEach and break/return in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

I am new to JS and I have a question about the return statement.
Why do I have to use return false to get out a forEach loop in JS?

This here works fine:

```
let answer;
    let found = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < database.length; i++){
        let p = database[i];
        if (p.id === person.id){
            database[i] = person; //Overwrite if found
            answer = 'Person information changed.';
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

But this on the other hand doesn't work:

```
database.forEach(element => {
        if(element.email == req.body.email || element.nachname == req.body.nachname || element.vorname == req.body.vorname)
            res.send(element);
            break;
    });
```

I got this error -> SyntaxError: Illegal break statement.

Is there any difference between those loops?
I know you can break a loop like for, while and switch loop but what makes forEach different?

Thank you!

Comment: break doesn't work inside forEach,  see [this](https://www.codepunker.com/blog/3-javascript-loop-gotchas) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260756/how-to-stop-javascript-foreach)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break

Comment: @Ramesh — The question has already observed that. It is asking why.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach  There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method is the wrong too.

Answer (score 2):

Reason is that we are passing a callback function to `forEach` function. Meaning you can't use loop conditions such as `break` and `continue`.

Answer (score 1):

Code running inside a `forEach` is in a *different function*.