# How to break a loop in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a the below code, on which i am unable to break the loop on certain conditions.

Expected Result : Error message should appear and user should be able to close the message and remove the escalation node properly

Actual Result : User Cannot remove the Error message by clicking ok..it automatically disappear within several minutes

```
public findVerticesBelow(vertexId: number) {
    // debugger
    this.recussionTime++;
    if(this.recussionTime <= 150){
        console.log(this.recussionTime)
        if (!this.vertexIdList.includes(vertexId)) {
            this.vertexIdList.push(vertexId)
          }
          let tempvertexIdList: Array<number> = new Array<number>();
          this.edges.forEach(edge => {
            if (edge.fromId == vertexId) {
              tempvertexIdList.push(edge.toId);
            }
          })

          tempvertexIdList.forEach(tempvertexId => {
            this.findVerticesBelow(tempvertexId)
          });
    }else{
        // debugger
        console.log("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")
        // alert("You are having a recursive loop please remove it before trying to remove nodes")
        // alert("ASCDFVGBHN")
    }
  }
```

I want to break the code and return the boolean value, but I am unable to do it right now. Can anybody help me.

Comment: `break` doesn't work inside forEach, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260756/how-to-stop-javascript-foreach)

Comment: Hi @Ramesh How can I stop it. this console.log("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA") running every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not proper way but you can use it

```js
let a=[1,2,3,3,4,4,4];
try{
   a.forEach((x,y)=>{
    console.log(x);
    if(x==4){
       throw "break";
    }
   })
}catch(e){
console.log(e);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You cann't stop the forEach loop in any JavaScript or TypeScript file. If want to use break you can simply use the for loop.
[If you want to learn more click here!](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/3-things-you-didnt-know-about-the-foreach-loop-in-js-ff02cec465b1)

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to break from forEach normally.Use the for loop instead of forEach.

There are 3 things which you might have not known about the forEach loop.

1. "return" doesn’t stop looping.
2. You cannot ‘break’.
3. You cannot ‘continue’.

Read more :
https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/3-things-you-didnt-know-about-the-foreach-loop-in-js-ff02cec465b1

Or

you can use Array.every() if you wish to return false while breaking the loop.

If you want to return true, then you can use Array.some()