# Optamise way to match a word in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split, string-matching

I am trying to match word in javascript if i use **'if'** and **'split'** method each time I stuck in the **case-sensetive**.

If I am using regExp then if a part of word matched it returned true **(i.e : hii , /hi/)**. What I do do to match case-insensitive and whole word should be match.

#### Code of the regEx

```
async function matchOne(str ,mtc) {
  let returnval;
  let words = str.split(' ')
  await words.forEach(word => {
    if (word.match(mtc)) {
      returnval = true;
      return true
    }
  });
  if (returnval === true) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
matchOne(string,regEx)
```

#### Code of the if  statement

```
async function matchOne(str ,mtc) {
  let returnval;
  let words = str.split(' ')
  await words.forEach(word => {
    if (word == mtc) {
      returnval = true;
      return true
    }
  });
  if (returnval === true) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

matchOne(string,string)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey there check out the code snippet below hopefully that should help you

```
const str = 'arya stark';

// The most concise way to check substrings ignoring case is using
// `String#match()` and a case-insensitive regular expression (the 'i')
str.match(/Stark/i); // true
str.match(/Snow/i); // false
```

In case you want to use forEach then consider converting the string to lowercase and search for a lowercase version of the word as shown below

```
str.toLowerCase().includes('Stark'.toLowerCase()); // true
str.toLowerCase().indexOf('Stark'.toLowerCase()) !== -1; // true
```

Comment: `What I do do to match case-insensitive and whole word should be match.` Can this also solve for whole words? Example `the boy spoke starkly` should not match.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you.

I have removed some code for clarity.

```
function matchOne(str ,mtc) {
  let returnval;
  let words = str.split(' ')
  words.forEach(word => {
    console.log(word)
    if (word.toLower().match(mtc)) {
      console.log('Found word:'+ word + ' regexp='+mtc)
      returnval = true;
    } else console.log('NOT Found word:'+ word  + ' regexp='+mtc)
  });
  return returnval;
}
matchOne('Hello world','he'); // true
matchOne('Hello world','He'); // true
```

As for Upper/Lower case. You need to decide if input & regexp should be upper or lower or whatever.
Just append `.toLower()` to your argument.

Example: `word.toLower().match(mtc)`

Answer (score 0):

You can match a string with regexp and use the global and case-insensitive flags

```js
let str = 'this string have Capital and no capital';

let match = str.match(/capital/gi);

console.log(match);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Regex matching

Considering that regex will match the whole string, splitting the string into words is not necessary.

```js
const regex = /hello/gi
const string = "hello world"
console.log(!!string.toLowerCase().match(regex)); // true

const string2 = "HELLO WORLD"
console.log(!!string2.toLowerCase().match(regex)); // true

const string3 = "WORLD ABC"
console.log(!!string3.toLowerCase().match(regex)); // false
```

Here `i` makes the regex matching case insensitive. `!!` is used to convert the array we receive after matching to a boolean.

2. String matching

You can simplify and clean up your code further - something like this.
We split the string by words. This will give us an array of words. Now we check if at least one word equates to your match.

```js
function matchOne(string, mtc) {
  return string.split(' ').some(word => word.toLowerCase() === mtc.toLowerCase())
}

console.log('hello world', 'hello'); // true
console.log('world abc', 'hello'); // false
```

Comment: Also some comments about your code snippet.

 1. `async-await` is not needed here for forEach.
 2. There is no need to return a value within `forEach`. In such a context, use `map`.
 Read more here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426458/javascript-difference-between-foreach-and-map

Comment: I added return value beacause I just want to stop the loop if condition match. Here I am using split method if the last word not matched then it set the value of returnval to false. And I dont want it so i do that to stop the loop

Comment: I think It will work:- `async function matchOne(str ,mtc) {
  let returnval;
  let words = str.split(' ')
  await words.forEach(word => {
    if (word.toLowerCase() == mtc.toLowerCase()) {
      returnval = true;
      return true;
    }
  });
  if (returnval === true) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

matchOne(string,string)`

Comment: " I just want to stop the loop if condition match" => you can't break a forEach.
Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260756/how-to-stop-javascript-foreach