# Why would for loop and forEach work different?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Here's the simple LeetCode function to find duplicates in the given array.

```
function findDuplicates(nums) {
    let hash = {}
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (!hash[nums[i]]) {
            hash[nums[i]] = true
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
    
    return false
}
```

It works great. But what's going to happen if we switch to forEach method instead?

```
function findDuplicates(nums) {
    let hash = {}
    nums.forEach(el => {
        if (!hash[el]) {
            hash[el] = true
        } else {
            return true
        }
    });

    return false
}
```

This function will not work with the same input of `[0,4,5,3,0,6]`.
Could you please explain why these two solutions give different results? Or just point me to the right direction.

Comment: In the first example you are `return`ing in the `findDuplicates` function, stopping it immediatly. In the second one, you are `return`ing in the `forEach`, which does not stop the other iterations from running (and it's useless to `return` a value in a `forEach`, as it won't be usable anywhere)

Comment: Use `for (const el of nums) {` instead. Also I would recommend a `Set` instead of that `hash = {}`.

Comment: ... or, using [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), simply `return nums.every((el, i) => nums.indexOf(el) === i);` (without any `for` or `forEach`)

Comment: @blex what's bigO of this function? using hash = {} makes it O(n)

Comment: I have no idea how to calculate that, but yes, using this will be less efficient than storing the encountered values in a `hash` variable (for `every` element, it will execute `indexOf`, which will internally loop too). Won't matter in most everyday uses (it makes the code easier to read IMO, and the time difference won't be noticeable), but if you have huge datasets it will indeed have an impact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return statement is equivalent of break, for loop can be broken, foreach can't be.

Comment: _"foreach can't be"_. That's not true. You can stop a `forEach` from looping (even though it's ugly): https://jsfiddle.net/pug02knh/

Comment: Refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260756/how-to-stop-javascript-foreach

Comment: Exactly. My method is like the second example in the provided answer